# Where to find issuer certificate

Tags: certificate, saml-2.0, xml-signature, opensso

I'm using OpenSSO 8 which I haven't configured myself. It's fully configured and without any problems. My problem is that I need to find the issuer certificate used to validate digital signatures on the SAML credentials. Can you tell me where should I look for it?

Answer (score 1):

You usually get the certificate in the metadata. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-5986/ghmlp/index.html) is a link on how to exchange the metadata from OpenSSO

The certificates are actually stored in opensso/opensso folder and can be exported using keytool

Comment: Thank you very much Stefan. Can you please give me instruction about one more thing? I have the certificate from the metadata, that's the one thing. When I log in SSO send to the client the request with the SAML message using other certificate, it's placed in samlp:Response/saml:Assertion/ds:Signature/ds:KeyInfo/ds:X509Data/ds:X509Certificate tag. Can you tell me how these two certificates are connected? What's the second certificate and how to handle it?

Comment: I would say generally these are the same